# Accurately predicting the wrong value

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I'm a python hobbyist and ML noob, and I thought I'd try to see if I can do a little stock market prediction. I'm by no means educated in this area and very much not a math boff.
I have however managed to get a pretty accurate prediction of the wrong value, and hoping that a great ML guru will point me in the right direction.

Firstly in my master dataframe (data) I calculate the Bollinger Bands, three DEMAs (12, 26, 100) and the MACD, then I shift the Close column of my stock data with -15 in to a "predict" column, which is supposed to be the value I would like to predict, 15 ticks in to the future.

I then split the last 200 rows out in to a separate dataframe (data1) that I will use to test my model against.

Here's how it goes;

```
# Create an empty dataframe with only the index of the original
test_data = pd.DataFrame(index=data.index)
# converting in to percentage of Close
test_data['b_upper'] = data['b_upper'] / data['Close']
test_data['b_middle'] = data['b_middle'] / data['Close']
test_data['b_lower'] = data['b_lower'] / data['Close']
test_data['dema1'] = data['dema1'] / data['Close']
test_data['dema2'] = data['dema2'] / data['Close']
test_data['dema3'] = data['dema3'] / data['Close']
# keep MACD
test_data['macd'] = data['macd']
test_data['macdsignal'] = data['macdsignal']
test_data['macdhist'] = data['macdhist']
# convert predict to a percentage of Close
test_data['predict'] = data['predict'] / data['Close']

split = int( len(test_data) * 0.8 )
train, test = test_data[:split], test_data[split:]
Xcols = ['b_upper', 'b_middle', 'b_lower', 'dema1', 'dema2', 'dema3', 'macd', 'macdsignal', 'macdhist']
ycols = ['predict']

train_X = train[Xcols].values
train_y = train[ycols].values.ravel()
test_X = test[Xcols].values
test_y = test[ycols].values.ravel()

data_1 = pd.DataFrame(index=data1.index)

# converting in to percentage of Change
data_1['b_upper'] = data1['b_upper'] / data1['Close']
data_1['b_middle'] = data1['b_middle'] / data1['Close']
data_1['b_lower'] = data1['b_lower'] / data1['Close']
data_1['dema1'] = data1['dema1'] / data1['Close']
data_1['dema2'] = data1['dema2'] / data1['Close']
data_1['dema3'] = data1['dema3'] / data1['Close']
# keep MACD
data_1['macd'] = data1['macd']
data_1['macdsignal'] = data1['macdsignal']
data_1['macdhist'] = data1['macdhist']
# convert predict to a percentage of Close
data_1['predict'] = data1['predict'] / data1['Close']
data_X = data_1[Xcols].values

reg = AdaBoostRegressor( ExtraTreeRegressor(), n_estimators=100, random_state=np.random.RandomState(1) )
reg.fit(train_X, train_y)
p = reg.predict(test_X)

print 'AdaBoostRegressor'
print 'Score:', reg.score(test_X, test_y)
print 'Mean Sq Err:', mean_squared_error(p, test_y)
print 'Obj:', get_size(reg), 'bytes'
```

Which returns:

```
AdaBoostRegressor
Score: -0.064949432102
Mean Sq Err: 0.000173545187532
Obj: 131550 bytes
```

So far so good, but when I predict with it, it gets me the actual Close value pretty accurately and not the predicted close 15 ticks in to the future:

```
p = reg.predict(data_X)
data1['predicted'] = data1['Close'] * p
data1[['Close','predict', 'predicted']].head(6)
```

Returning:

```
                    Close   predict predicted
datetime            
2016-05-28 18:15:00 501.00  532.98  501.890391
2016-05-28 18:30:00 501.57  537.34  499.006097
2016-05-28 18:45:00 500.28  532.00  499.654848
2016-05-28 19:00:00 500.28  535.39  499.897474
2016-05-28 19:15:00 501.97  535.23  499.415860
2016-05-28 19:30:00 501.12  531.74  502.4060
```

Plotting this out shows how it's predicting (red) the actual Close (light blue) where I was expecting it to predict the "predict" value (green):
[image: plot]
I've tried this just about every way I could Google  but still end up predicting the present and not the future.  I'm pretty sure I'm missing something fundamental, and your advice would be very much appreciated to get this noob a better understanding of what it takes to predict the future.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Stock prices are in general chaotic. Prediction made at one point of time will have exponentially increasing error bound as time goes. You are observing this exact phenomena in your data and model. Of course, there are other point of views on this matter. More on this please read: https://www.amazon.com/Essentials-Stochastic-Finance-Models-Theory/dp/9810236050